# How to extract features from image for classification and object recognition?

Tags: image-processing, emgucv, svm, object-recognition, feature-extraction

I'm confused about the way I should make the "features extraction " method 
I want to use SVMs to apply "Object recognition" in images ,
There's a sample in Emgu's examples that holds an XML file contains the features of a cat !
and I've been trying since a week to know how they did it and what methods they used 
and I came across this page 
http://experienceopencv.blogspot.com/2011/02/learning-deformable-models-with-latent.html
that displays the steps ! It's so complicated plus couldn't do it myself
I'm so lost !! can anyone tell me an appropriate method of  "features extraction "Compatible with SVMs learning ?
Accord has SVM example but it's on hand writing and doesn't deal with color images =(
any helping links ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

all feature extraction methods are compatible with svm... u just need to choose one... select one and get the features and then input these features into svm.... explanation of what is feature extraction is here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction

Comment: Thank you , I've read all these pages and yet I can't find the appropriate feature extraction method for my project "image understanding"

Comment: i use Local Binary Pattern and Gabor filter for my feature extraction... maybe u want to search on them...

Answer (score 0):

You need to concentrate on the gabor filter, which is an advanced extractor for face recognition and object recognition.