# how can I get the xml files of models for object detection?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, emgucv, svm, object-detection

I'm having a big troubles with the libraries that I have to use in my project .
whenever I tried one of the libraries , a problem appears and I don't have so much time to get lost for all this time :( my project is "Image Understanding"
so I need a "feature extraction" & "image segmentation " & "Machine learning" 
after reading , it turned out the " SVM " is the best one
and I want some code to build mine on it and start off .

---

1- first I looked at "Aforge & Accord" and there was an example named "SupportVectorMachine" but it's not on images .

---

2- I found a great example in "EmguCV" named "LatentSvmDetector" and it detected any image of cat I tried it !! but the problem was in the xml file ! 
I just wanted to know how they got it ! and I couldn't find a simple answer 
actually I asked you here and no body answers me :(

[link] [How to extract features from image for classification and object recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328231/how-to-extract-features-from-image-for-classification-and-object-recognition)

---

3- I found an example uses opencv here in this site

[link] http://www.di.ens.fr/~laptev/download.html
but the same problem : xml file ?!!! 
I tried to take the xml file of this example and tried in the "EmguCV" example but it didn't work either .

---

4- in all the papers that I read they're using "ImageNet" & "VOC PASCAL" , I downloaded them and they're not working !! errors in the code of the tool !! and I've fixed them all 
but yet they're not compailing , those tool are written in "Matlab"
here's my qusetion on this site :
[link] [Matlab Mex32 link error while compiling Felzenszwalb VOC on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602464/mex32-link-error)
for god sake can anybody tell me what should I do ?! 
I'm running out of time , need your help ! 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, because I never used SVM (but used haartraining) but I think that they have trained the detector using a program that outputs a xml file at the end of the training. I have made a quick search and found this [link](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html) (opencv doc about svm training) and this [link](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/08/25/a-simple-object-classifier-with-bag-of-words-using-opencv-2-3-w-code/) (a post with a example). I hope that it helps you and give some light.

Comment: actually the example you gave me is exactly what I need !
but I'm still having problems with it , because of the " cmake " can you help or I have to post another question for it ?

Comment: Which problem you have with the cmake? If possible, please show the output. I'll try to help :)

Comment: I post it as a question here
[link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742052/cmake-is-not-working-in-opencv-c-project/9743635#comment12394012_9743635

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB supports xml files - both reading and writing. Try:

```
 xmlfile = fullfile(matlabroot, 'path/to/xml/file/myfile.xml');
 xDoc = xmlread(xmlfile)
```

If you don't have xmlread function they you can try this toolbox: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4278-xml-toolbox

Comment: It's not a reading problem but I'm asking if anyone knows how they got it in all those tools ?