# CMake adding opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to include opencv2.4.9 with cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(HydroCamel)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lpthread")
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)
catkin_package()
set(SRC_FOLDER src/src)
set(ALOGS_FOLDER src/Algos)
set(ALOGS_UTILS_FOLDER src/Algos/Utils)
set(SRC_INCLUDE_FOLDER src/include)
set(DIRS ${SRC_FOLDER} ${ALOGS_FOLDER} ${ALOGS_UTILS_FOLDER} ${SRC_INCLUDE_FOLDER})
include_directories(${DIRS})

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES "*.h" "*.cpp")
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
find_package(Boost 1.55.0 COMPONENTS filesystem system thread)
#FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc highgui)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
    add_executable(SourceFiles ${SRC_FILES})
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(SourceFiles ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(SourceFiles ${OpenCV_LIBS})
endif()
```

And I receive this error:

> CMake Error at HydroCamel/CMakeLists.txt:28 (find_package):   Found
>   package configuration file:
>
> ```
> /home/jdorfsman/opencv-2.4.9/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake
> ```
>
> but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered
>   to be   NOT FOUND.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/jdorfsman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also
>   "/home/jdorfsman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

This is the CMakeError.log file:

```
Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/jdorfsman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec1061744568/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1061744568.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1061744568.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jdorfsman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/jdorfsman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1061744568.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1061744568.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/jdorfsman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec1061744568
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1061744568.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1061744568.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec1061744568 -rdynamic 
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1061744568.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec1061744568] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jdorfsman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec1061744568/fast] Error 2

File /home/jdorfsman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/jdorfsman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec3426763052/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3426763052.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3426763052.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jdorfsman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/jdorfsman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3426763052.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3426763052.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec3426763052
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3426763052.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3426763052.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec3426763052 -rdynamic -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec3426763052] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jdorfsman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec3426763052/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: See the **.log** files as the error message suggest. [Maybe these instructions can help you.](http://answers.opencv.org/question/35125/cmake-linking-error-opencv_found-to-false-ubuntu-1304/)

Comment: What happens if you set the environment variable `OpenCV_DIR` by doing something like `export OpenCV_DIR=/home/jdorfsman/opencv-2.4.9/build`, revome the `set(OpenCV_DIR...)` and re-run cmake ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846171/cmake-still-not-working-with-opencv

Comment: Same thing sadly.
`Found package configuration file:
/home/jdorfsman/opencv-2.4.9/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake
but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be NOT FOUND.`

Comment: @karlphillip I saw the log message, and also saw the link you refer me to, sadly it isn't the same error and the log didn't helped much. I'll add it to the question in case it helps..

Comment: Not sure why it is looking for `pthreads` instead of `pthread`. Can you try setting `OpenCV_DIR` to OpenCV install directory and not the build directory. I mean set it to path where `make install` copied the built libraries.

Comment: @Kiran I tried to set the OpenCV_DIR variable in the .bashrc file to /usr/local/lib, where it is installed and I still get the same message.. I'll add the whole cmake file in the question, maybe that will pour some light on the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't specify the pthread flag.

```
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1061744568.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec1061744568] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jdorfsman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec1061744568/fast] Error 2
```

try add:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lpthread")
```

Comment: could you run `make VERBOSE=1` and copy paste the output in your post?

Comment: I uploaded it here: https://mega.co.nz/#!LYkQGAQB!BttwK0a5uVT0XCM9TcBoaaN0tgSH4pjUMfUVBIKXcPQ
Thanks!